# Getting jQuery AJAX to work in Wordpress (getting -1)

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am trying to figure out how to use jQuery `$.ajax()` for a project. I setup this test using what I learned from [TutsPlus.com](http://wp.tutsplus.com/articles/getting-started-with-ajax-wordpress-pagination/). Everything seems to be working correctly except I am getting a `-1` returned. So I get an alert with `Success: -1` and `#test-div1` is populated with `-1`, instead of `Hello Everyone!`.

**My HTML:**

```
<input type="hidden" name="GreetingAll" id="GreetingAll" value="Hello Everyone!" />  
<input class="btn" type="submit" id="PleasePushMe" />  
<div id="test-div1"></div>
```

**In functions.php:**

```
function add_myjavascript(){  
  wp_enqueue_script( 'ajax-implementation.js', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . "/scripts/ajax-implementation.js", array( 'jquery' ) );  
}  

add_action( 'init', 'add_myjavascript' );

function MyAjaxFunction(){  
  //get the data from ajax() call  
   $GreetingAll = $_POST['GreetingAll'];  
   $results = "<h2>".$GreetingAll."</h2>";  
  // Return the String  
   die($results);  
}  
// creating Ajax call for WordPress  
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_MyAjaxFunction', 'MyAjaxFunction' );  
add_action( 'wp_ajax_MyAjaxFunction', 'MyAjaxFunction' );
```

**ajax-implementation.js:**

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {  

    var GreetingAll = jQuery("#GreetingAll").val();  

    jQuery("#PleasePushMe").click(function(){ 
      jQuery.ajax({  
            type: 'POST',  
            url: '/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php',  
            data: {  
                action: 'MyAjaxFunction',  
                GreetingAll: GreetingAll,  
            },  
            success: function(data, textStatus, XMLHttpRequest){  
                alert('Success: ' + data);
                jQuery("#test-div1").html('');  
                jQuery("#test-div1").append(data);  
            },  
            error: function(MLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown){  
                alert(errorThrown);  
            }  
        });  
  });

});
```

My only modification is changing `get_bloginfo('template_directory')` to `get_stylesheet_directory_uri()`, because I am using a child theme.

Any thoughts on how I can get this working? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

1st) Add another dependency: `array( 'json2', 'jquery' );`.

2nd) Dig into [wp-localize-script](/questions/tagged/wp-localize-script) and read about [`wp-localize-script()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_localize_script) in Codex. It allows you to send data from PHP to javascript via an javascript var, set in PHP (as 2nd arg for `wp_localize_script()`).

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I have updated `wp_enqueue_script( 'ajax-implementation.js', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . "/scripts/ajax-implementation.js", array( 'json2', 'jquery' ) )`. I have read about `wp-localize-script`, but not sure how you are suggesting using it in this case. With just adding `json2`, I am still getting `-1`.

Comment: Please read some of the answers in detail - you'll see how to pass vars from php to js. and proper fire the result.

Answer (score 0):

Just add at the end of your ajax function (in the PHP file) `die();` and after your echo `"your  output"` it will get rid of that 0.

(Sorry if late I just found this question)

Answer (score 0):

In your ajax call,
Just

```
echo $results;
```

Then do

```
die();
```

Eg:

```
echo $results;
die();
```